# Nginx + php7.0-fpm = blank page

Tags: php, http, nginx, cgi

I've just installed nginx and php7.0-fpm on clear debian 9 and tried to configure it by standard way, but when i try to access http://mysite/test.php i get blank page. There aren't any errors in /var/log/nginx/error.log or /var/log/php7.0-fpm.log files (i get 200 answers, but page is blank). My configs files below..

**/var/www/html/test.php**

```
<?php phpinfo(); ?>
```

**nginx.conf**

```
http {
access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name _;

    root /var/www/html;
    index test.php;
    location ~* \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
            include /etc/nginx/fastcgi.conf;
            fastcgi_pass  127.0.0.1:9000;
    }

}
#include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
#include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}
```

**/etc/php/7.0/fpm/pool.d/www.conf**

```
[www]
user = www-data
group = www-data
listen = 127.0.0.1:9000
listen.owner = www-data
listen.group = www-data
```

Comment: Also i have 777 permissions for /var/www/html/test.php and /etc/nginx/fastcgi.conf file.

Comment: have you restarted the services?

Comment: @Ice76, sure, php and nginx were restarted

Comment: never give 777 permission even for the sake of testing. 665 is okay, but if you are thinking in such a way, that even just for your satisfaction don't go beyond 775.

Answer (score 2):

Try to pass the socket path instead of server:port:

```
fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
```

Also, the `server_name _;` will work only if a default server is [specified](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html), are you sure the 200 code comes from from the url you requested (you should rule out possible failbacks to other vhost)?

Comment: from acces log:
my_ip - - [10/Oct/2018:10:02:17 +0000] "GET /test.php HTTP/1.1" 200 28 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/69.0.3497.100 Safari/537.36"

Comment: I can connect to 127.0.0.1 9000 with telnet, i think problem is not here. I have already tried to configure fastcgi_pass and php-fpm with unix socket - it doesn't work.

Comment: i know it could be dumb, but try to print php error inside your page error_reporting(E_ALL); and ini_set('display_errors', 1);

Answer (score 0):

Try adding:

    `fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $realpath_root/test.php;`

You shouldn't have to 777 anything.